# Actionscript 3 removing swf audio does not stop

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to add an swf for a game cut scene but I have a problem of audio repeating after removeChild and setting the object to null. I'm trying to add the file and remove it after the length of frames in the animation (721) and remove it to move on to other things.

I've also tried cutscenes[0].stop(); and SoundMixer.stopAll(); as suggested by other posts.

removechild() does remove the visual aspect of the file/animation but not the audio, and it repeats after the amount of time of the length of the animation (721 frames) as though it is being reloaded. How can I stop the audio?

```
    package {
import flash.display.*;
    import flash.media.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
                import flash.events.*;
   [SWF(backgroundColor="#0000ff", frameRate="24", width="640", height="480")]
public class main extends MovieClip
{
    [Embed(source="/Cutscenes/Intro_Scene 1.swf")]
    private var scene1:Class
    public var cutscenes:Array = new Array();
    public var scene_exists:Boolean = false;
    public var scene_timer:Number = 0;
    public function main()
    {
        scene_exists = false;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, play_intro);
    }

    public function play_intro(event:Event):void
    {
        scene_timer++;
        if (scene_exists == false) //Add cutscene
        {
            cutscenes[0] = new scene1();
            addChild(cutscenes[0]);
            scene_exists = true;
        }

        if (scene_timer == 721) //Remove cutscene
        {
            SoundMixer.stopAll();
            scene_exists = false;
            removeChild(cutscenes[0]);
            cutscenes[0] = null;
            scene_timer = 0;
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, play_intro);
                            //Do next thing
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried loading the SWF through the Loader class as opposed to directly embedding it, and then calling the unloadAndStop method on the Loader?  Note, you can embed the bytes for the SWF and manually feed them into the Loader through the loadBytes method, if you need to embed the data instead of loading it at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the issue, but try stopping the cutscene like this :

```
 cutscenes[0].stop();
```

Then do the `SoundMixer.stopAll();` etc.

My thought is that the timeline of the .swf will keep playing and even repeat if not stopped.

Removing a DisplayObject from the display list does not stop the animation/audio from playing, it's just removing it from the display list.